# Hide iframes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to create a browser (I got bored) and I want the user to be able to navigate between tabs.
This would need me to hide one iframe and show another one. I'm not sure how to do this using javascript. I also don't want the iframe to resize (like saying `height: 0px;`).

[Here](https://7emrv.csb.app/)'s my sandbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your iframe inside a div container and when you need to hide it just add a style or class to it and set it display style to none

html

```
<div class="hide">

    <iframe></iframe>

</div>
```

css

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked this solution thinking that it would need some complicated js. The idea of using css didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom CSS to your iframe dynamically to hide and show.

Refer following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.custom-style {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="iframe"
    width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zFZrkCIc2Oc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    
   <br/>
    
    <button onclick="onHide();">Hide Me<button>
    
    <button onclick="onShow();">Show Me<button>
    

</body>

<script>

    function onHide() {
        document.getElementById('iframe').classList.add('custom-style');
    }
    
    function onShow() {
        document.getElementById('iframe').classList.remove('custom-style');
    
    }
 
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is good but in my question I said that I don't want my iframe to resize. In this  answer, you resize your iframe to 0px x 0px which is not what I want.